# Faces Exception Handling , JSF 1.2 Padding Oracle Exception

Tags: exception

I need to handle Faces Exception thrown and display custom page on being caught.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I tried overriding the MyFaces exception in web.xml and created a separate bean for handling all the bad request.It worked for me.